# Spark streaming (v2.1.0) refers to Kafka (v.0.10.0) brokers with their hostname (not their IP addr)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I use the following Kafka settings:

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "10.30.3.41:9092,10.30.3.42:9092,10.30.3.43:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "123",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)
```

All the Kafka brokers are defined with their corresponding IP addresses (as shown above).

However, when I start the streaming context, I get the following error:

```
16/12/31 01:46:06 DEBUG NetworkClient: Error connecting to node 1 at broker1:9092:
java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: broker1:9092
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:171)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:498)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$400(NetworkClient.java:48)
...
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:168)
    ... 31 more
```

**broker1** is the hostname of my broker. Since I am not setting up DNS in the cluster, this name is not resolvable from all nodes. I can solve this issue by properly adding all the broker hostnames on `/etc/hosts` across all nodes. Unfortunately, I really don't want to manage `/etc/hosts`, and I really want to understand why Spark doesn't just connects to the brokers via their IP addresses as I explicitly list them under `bootstrap.servers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is more an issue with your Kafka configuration than Spark. Probably `listeners` and `advertised.listeners` are not set or are configured to use host name. If thats indeed the case these values are advertised to the consumers and result in the observed behavior.

Configuring brokers to use IP addresses for these properties should resolve the problem:

```sh
# Adjust security protocol according to your requirements
# and replace public_host_ip with desired IP 
listeners=PLAINTEXT://public_host_ip:9092 # or 0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://public_host_ip:9092
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate where we need to set this properties? I'm using azure databricks.